# Configuração Instancia Tomcat / NGinx java sprintg

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, nginx

Preciso configurar uma nova instancia do tomcat para hospedar uma nova aplicação e em paralelo a isso configurar o nginx para fazer o proxy reverso.

A aplicação está desenvolvida em java Spring. A aplicação é dois pacotes front e um back que vai servir de API para as demais. Estou com duvida para fazer a API funcionar no caso o /adm ...

Preciso de ajuda para configurar o API correto.

Já fiz a nova instancia, já configurei o server no nginx mais ainda sim não está fazendo a comunicação com a API.

Comment: E qual e o problema mesmo? Inclua o que fez, possíveis erros que estejam acontencendo - log do nginx - etc

Answer (score -1):

Esses links pode lhe ajudar

[how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[securing-tomcat-running-behind-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-load-balancer](https://medium.com/@apuravchauhan/securing-tomcat-running-behind-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-load-balancer-c2a313602669)